# Java Volley Request Multipart Form with Image Data

Tags: java, android-studio, android-volley, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload data to my web app using a REST API. I need to send an image with other parameters as multipart data. I have the method below based on some posts that I have viewed on here. When the request is submitted it fails and from the server logs it looks like it is not reading the parameters and failing with the ID.

I am confused as how to structure the request using Volley. If I send the equivalent using Insomnia as shown below then it is successful. I have replicated using the same bearer token.

[image]

```
private void uploadPicture() {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(CameraActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading, please wait...");
    progressDialog.show();

    Log.d("URL", URL + PICNS);

    //converting image to base64 string
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Bitmap compressedImg = getResizedBitmap(imageBitmap,600);
    compressedImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    final String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

    Log.d("TOKEN", token);

    //sending image to server
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL + PICNS,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("RESPONSE", response.toString());
        }

    },new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Log.d("Error", volleyError.toString());
            Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Some error occurred -> "+volleyError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
        }
    }) {
        //adding parameters to send
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parameters.put("route_id","1");
            parameters.put("lat","52.395728");
            parameters.put("lng","-1.992031");
            parameters.put("description", " ");
            parameters.put("caption", "Wow Uploaded This");
            parameters.put("picture", imageString);
            return parameters;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            return headers;
        }


    };

    RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(CameraActivity.this);
    rQueue.add(request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the library from [here](https://github.com/hardillb/MultiPartVolley) to get send the multipart request and it seems to be working for me.